# Bad stdio forwarding specification '%h:%p

Tags: mac, macos, ssh

I am on macOS Sierra, and my SSH version is :
`OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017`

I have this content in my `.ssh/config` :

```
Host db
  User user
  HostName 192.168.1.111
  ProxyCommand ssh user@db -W %h:%p

Host website
  User user
  HostName 192.168.1.100
  ProxyCommand ssh user@Website -W %h:%p
```

I also have a server with a public IP, that has direct connection with these two servers, I want to forward my SSH connection through this public server to my private servers (db and website).

When I use this command:

```
ssh user@db -W %h:%p
```

I get this error:

```
Bad stdio forwarding specification '%h:%p'
```

Now, what should I do to solve this problem and connect my macOS host to my private servers?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a ProxyCommand entry and you also add `-W %h:%p` on the command line. Shouldn't you pick one or the other and not both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your config file as well as the command are wrong.

The ProxyCommand line should contain the JumpHost's user/hostname **but not** the final destination.

Config file:

```
Host db
  User dbuser
  HostName 192.168.1.111 #db host name/IP
  ProxyCommand ssh user_public_server@public_server -W %h:%p

Host website
  User websiteuser
  HostName 192.168.1.100 #website host name/IP
  ProxyCommand ssh user_public_server@public_server -W %h:%p
```

The command is then simply `ssh db` or `ssh website` because the user friendly Host's name (e.g. db) as defined in the config file is expanded to the HostName/IP (e.g. 192.168.1.111).

Comment: still same error